# Continued Fraction Expansions Confusion

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $\theta$ be an irrational number with continued fraction expansion $[a_0; a_1, a_2, \cdots]$.

Suppose $P_n/Q_n = [a_0; a_1, \cdots , a_n]$ is the $n^{th}$ convergent. Then how do I show that $P_0=a_0$.

I have that $P_0/Q_0= [a_0]$ but where do I go from here?

Comment: Since $[a_0] = a_0$ is an integer, it follows immediately that $Q_0 = 1$, doesn't it?

Comment: is [a0] supposed to be the floor of a0?

Comment: Definitely not. $[a_0; a_1,a_2,\dotsc]$ is just a shorthand notation for the continued fraction of a number $\alpha$, with digits $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dotsc$. It is worth noting that the ';' separates the integer part of $\alpha$, $a_0$, from the digits of the fractional part of $\alpha$.

Comment: It is worth noting that there are multiple [different notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations_for_continued_fractions) for continued fractions.

Answer (score 2):

As you observed, the $n$-th convergent of the continued fraction $[a_0; a_1,a_2,\dotsc]$ is the rational number
$$
c_n = [a_0; a_1,\dotsc,a_n] =
a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1
    + \cfrac{1}{\ddots
    + \cfrac{1}{a_n}}}
$$
and the integers $p_n,q_n$ are simply numerator and denominator of $c_n$, respectively.

In particular, $c_0 = a_0 \in \Bbb{Z}$ has denominator $1$, so $p_0 = c_0$.

Comment: Could you please upvote and/or accept this answer if it satisfied you? That way this question won't pop up in the "unanswered" tab anymore.